# SQL Query selects the same data

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query, `rating_food`, `rating_service` and `rating_decor` returns the same value, for all my results.

```
select `restaurants`.*, `rating`.*, (rating.rating_food + rating.rating_service + rating.rating_decor) / 3 as rating_total from
(
SELECT
avg(reviews.rating_food) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_food,
avg(reviews.rating_service) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_service,
avg(reviews.rating_decor) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_decor
FROM restaurants
JOIN reviews ON reviews.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
)
as rating, restaurants
order by `rating_total` asc limit 12
```

Expected result:
A array of 12 results with three additional calculated columns (`rating_food` etc)

Right now i get 12 results but all their `rating_food`, `rating_service` and `rating_decor` returns the same value for all results.

Comment: Add a group by clause in the derived table? And a main query JOIN condition

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It may surprise you, but a non-functioning query does not necessarily do a good job of conveying what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff An explanation has been added.

Comment: Why no JOIN condition between rating and restaurants?

Comment: As written, you are cross joining all restaurants with all ratings.  You aren't correlating them.

Comment: How can i retrieve an ID from my main query to my subquery? (That would achieve my expected result, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join back your `ratings` subquery with the `restaurants` table.

Try this one:

```
select `restaurants`.*, `rating`.*, 
(rating.rating_food + rating.rating_service + rating.rating_decor) / 3 as rating_total from
(
SELECT
restaurants.id,
avg(reviews.rating_food) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_food,
avg(reviews.rating_service) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_service,
avg(reviews.rating_decor) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_decor
FROM restaurants
JOIN reviews ON reviews.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
GROUP by restaurants.id
)
as rating join restaurants on rating.id = restaurants.id
order by `rating_total` asc limit 12
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50b39/4/0

Comment: That returns 1 result. Expected 12

Comment: Fixed, a group by was missing. Linked new SQL Fiddle as well.

Comment: That fixed it! I added LEFT JOIN reviews to fetch all results even though they dont have a relation to any reviews.